# Kafka consumer group as a Springboot services does not consume related topic together

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have springboot service lets call it "consumerService". However, I created another instance of this service so there is one kafka consumer group which contains two instance of same service. And those services try to consume a topic with multiple partitions.

But only one of the instances consumes related topic meanwhile the other instance does nothing. Since they are in same consumer group why is one of them not consuming?

I tried to connect another kafka server with same scenario. I published messages one by one as manuel inputs with kafka producer on this kafka. When I published message two different instance, they shared them randomly as it should be. So what is the problem in the first kafka?

Comment: You may check if messages are sent to parititons which are consumed by the other instance. You can check the partiton log size.

Comment: 1) Show your code as a [mcve]. 2) Show what you've debugged, such as if messages truly get written to different partitions (you can use `GetOffsetShell` command for this)